# Yii2, why a model validation fails due to a missing mandatory attribute when that attribute is assigned by a Behavior?

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-validation

I have a Model with a
`[['creation_time'], 'integer']`
attribute which have a

```
[
    'class' => TimestampBehavior::className(),
    'createdAtAttribute' => 'creation_time'
]
```

behavior assigned.
If I mark this attribute as `required` it'll fail the model validation as if it's missing.
Why?
How can I mark it as required?

Comment: in the model rules [['creation_time'], 'required'], make it required, or you can set a scenario..

Comment: @Sfili_81 have you read the question?
If I do that it will fail the validation

Comment: If a field is required it's obvious that validation fails. probably  is unclear what do you want to achieve

Comment: Do you want to add required attribute in the html only?

Comment: @Sfili_81 it's not obvious because it should be assigned by the behavior

Comment: [https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/concept-behaviors#using-timestamp-behavior](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/concept-behaviors#using-timestamp-behavior)

Comment: @Sfili_81 that page does not state anything about TimestampBehavior **and** validation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in order in which the actions are performed.

The `creation_time` attribute is set by `yii\behaviors\TimestampBehavior` during the `BaseActiveRecord::EVENT_BEFORE_INSERT`. This event is invoked by `beforeSave()` callback.

If you take a look at [souce code](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/c5f7704a4d515f06efa66a94940db3aa24d02f6c/framework/db/ActiveRecord.php#L558) of `insert()` method in ActiveRecord you can see the order of actions is:

1. Validate
2. Call beforeSave
3. Do the insert
4. Call afterSave

So your model is first validated and then the `creation_time` is set. That's why validation of this attribute is failing.

If your `creation_time` is only set by `TimestampBehavior` then there is no need to validate it. If you want to allow editation of this attribute, then you can use [scenarios](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/structure-models#scenarios) to validate it only during editing.